# swing retrieve data from mysql db to textfield

Tags: java, mysql, swing

i have column in mysql table have 100 record ,i want show values from table inside textfield ( every 3 second show record from 0 - 99). this is my code :

```
Connection conn = null;
    Statement st = null;
    ResultSet rs = null;
    String dbUrl = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/jointdb";
    String dbUsr = "root";
    String dbPass = "a12345";
    try{
    String sql= "select expert1 from eridb";
    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    conn = DriverManager.getConnection (dbUrl,dbUsr,dbPass);
    st = conn.createStatement();
    rs = st.executeQuery(sql);
   // textField1.setText("enter text here");
    while(rs.next()){
        //Get values
        String value = rs.getString("expert1");
        textField1.setText(value);        
    }

}catch(Exception e){
    e.printStackTrace();
}finally{
    try {
        rs.close();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    try {
        st.close();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    try {
        conn.close();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Now, i want show value of record every 3 second from index 0-99 record

Note: Data come to database every 3 second 
thanks

Comment: [How to use Swing Timers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html) or [Worker Threads and SwingWorker](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/worker.html)

Comment: Use timertask to get your requirement

Comment: @Prabha can u assist me and edit on my code

Comment: If you're using Java 7 or newer, you might want to write this code using try-with-resources, this would greatly simplify your exception handling code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Thread.sleep(milliseconds)

```
while(rs.next()){
    String value = rs.getString("expert1");
    textField1.setText(value);        
    try {
          Thread.sleep(3000);
    } catch(Exception e) {}
}
```

You can use [Thread](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_multithreading.htm) for parallel process.

Comment: As far as I am aware, once a component becomes visible, it should only be manipulated via the event thread, isn't it? So, `textfield.setText(value);` needs to be scheduled for the event thread.

Comment: Learn about Thread as mentioned in my answer to start the process separately. After that it won't hang.

Comment: This is wrong. Thread.sleep(3000) blocks the UI. Putting the Thread.sleep(3000) into separate Thread still has the problem of textField not being updated on event thread. Apart from that the proposed solution keeps the ResultSet open for a long time and the refresh of the JTextField does not continue after the last value has been read from ResultSet.

Answer (score 0):

Please read [How To Use Swing Timer](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html) and [The Event Dispatch Thread](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html).

Use then javax.swing.Timer to re-read the data from database and set the content on the JTextField the way you need it.

```
Timer timer = new Timer(3000, new ActionListener() {

    @Override
     public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
         .... // retrieve data and prepare the textField content
         textField.setContent(...);
     }          
});

timer.start();
```